# select2 delay not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using below code to initialise select2 on a select box. But the **delay** is not working, requests are going to server immediately.

```
$(".multi_select").select2({
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    delay: 5000,
    ajax: {
      url: "/search.json",
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  });
```

Another problem I am facing is, I am getting **abort** error on fast typing, that means previous requests are not getting aborted. Yesterday when I added above code, without delay, it was working fine without 'abort' error. Today, it gives abort error, with and without delay along with failure of **delay**.

I am using v4.0.3 and there is no change in project since yesterday so I don't understand that what happened suddenly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for the abort error?

Comment: @Lukas I don’t remember exactly, but I vaguely remember that there was another piece of code which was causing this. I think it was `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` which acts like application-wide error handler and was changing settings of all Ajax calls. Though I don't remember why it was not throwing error one day and suddenly started throwing error for my function the other day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delay parameter has to be added to ajax section:

```
$(".multi_select").select2({
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "/search.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 5000
    }
});
```

See: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#rate-limiting-requests

Comment: I missed that. Can you help me with that abort error which get caught in the $.ajaxSetup whenever I type fast or backspace fast ?

Comment: Please share more details and more code. Anyway I suggest to use the latest version of Select2 (4.0.5 or 4.0.6-rc.1)